# What is the best way to stop the bleeding from a shaving cut?

Tags: personal-care, shaving

Sometimes when I shave I accidently cut myself (usually due to haste).
I was wondering what is the best way to stop the bleeding and gives the most comfort.

I heard the paper from cigarettes or toilet paper help, but the question is:
 
**Are there any other ways to stop the bleeding and continue or finish up on the shave?**

P.S. this is my first question on stack overflow, so tips and pointers are welcome to better my questions and answers!

Comment: I'm going to point this out, as most people don't even know it exists. A Styptic Pencil is designed for this exact purpose. It's a little white stick that costs about 3 bucks. http://www.amazon.com/Clubman-Styptic-Pencil-Travel-Size/dp/B00E5QJC04

Comment: Also, google is your friend here. While I support this question because I haven't seen it on this site, it has been answered elsewhere. (I own a styptic pencil, as mentioned above, but never use it as I don't cut myself.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way to stop bleeding from a minor cut like a shaving nick is to apply direct pressure (a clean fingertip does the job nicely) for at least two minutes.

If you take blood thinners or have a low-grade clotting disorder, it might take *ten to thirty* minutes or more for clotting to occur, and the time must be restarted if you remove the pressure and bleeding restarts.  If you have full-blown hemophilia, you shouldn't be shaving at all, by any method (even an electric razor can skim off raised skin around a follicle and cause bleeding), though your doctor may suggest a trimmer with a suitable guard to control beard length.

Obviously, if you have to hold pressure for ten minutes or more to stop bleeding, you'll need to reapply your choice of shaving foam or soap before you can finish shaving, but if that applies to you, you should consider shaving by a method less likely to cause bleeding, such as an electric foil shaver.

Comment: With all due respect, this is a medical remedy rather than a lifehack.

Comment: Medical problem (bleeding), medical or first aid remedy.  There isn't anything simpler than direct pressure, and for most people with common shaving-cut size wounds it'll get the job done fast enough to finish shaving before the foam dries out.

Comment: @VarunKN And it _is_ best pointed out that if it were to bleed heavily or for a long period of time that you may have another issue to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

These are 5 alternatives to toilet paper:

**1. Deodorant**

Most antiperspirants contain aluminum chloride that can, in addition to shrinking sweat glands, constrict blood vessels and clot a nick.

**2. Lip Balm**

Smearing on a little ChapStick or Vaseline works like a seal—plus it’ll keep bigger cuts from forming unsightly scabs.

**3. Ice Cubes**

Like swimming pools and your package, the cold shrinks blood vessels, enabling a clot to form fast.

**4. Mouthwash**

The alcohol in solutions like Listerine acts as an astringent, which halts blood flow by causing tissues to contract.

**5. Eye Drops**

Red eye relievers like Visine work similarly on cuts: they slow down bleeding by constricting blood vessels

Comment: Isn't using deodorant on wounds really bad?

Comment: @Kiwi it shouldn't. Also it contains aluminium which is the ingredient that we need to heal

Comment: just wondering is all, because it contains aluminium indeed, but also contains other stuff which maybe harmful?

Comment: @Kiwi the deodorant is a product made specifically to apply in the skin. As all products, there are several types from soft to strong, but when use it as a remedy to heal the skin, you just need to apply a tiny bit :)

Comment: -1 for deodorant.  Most of the packages I've read say "don't apply to broken skin" or recommend not applying immediately after shaving under the arms, strongly implying they aren't good for your freshly cut face, either.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy an Alum shaving block. These are very cheap, and when you make them wet, and then rub them (softly) over the cut, the alum will make it close.

I use one when shaving with a cut-throat razor. Not necessarily because of cuts, but it also helps with irritation I find.

Comment: Known as a Styptic Pencil.

Comment: @Tetsujin : that works, but I was refering to one of these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIL0-HDmpfw